# Supermicro motherboard and upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: motherboard

My motherboard is Supermicro X10SRA-F Version 1.01. Can I safely upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with respect to compatibility?
Thanks

Comment: Note that because you are currently on 14.04 LTS, by default, the update manager doesn't offer to let you upgrade to 16.04 until the first point release, i.e., 16.04.1, is available. You can still force it to upgrade to it before the first point release if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading distributions to a newer version rarely causes hardware support issues because in the kernel, support for hardware is rarely (if not never) removed, only added.

If you really want to be sure, try it with a live usb with 16.04 without installing it, that usually is a good indicator of what to expect when you actually install it. And if that works, you can be quite sure that it will work.